# How to separate code signing settings from xcodeproj files?

Tags: xcode

We have a Git repo setup where it is extremely helpful to check-in not only the source but also the project.xcodeproj directory in order for new developers to start working.

But the challenge is that each dev has different code signing settings and these are overwritten by folks when they commit their changes. Right now we know only that this data comes over as part of the files inside project.xcodeproj directory. Can anyone tell us how to externalize the code signing properties or the name of the file that should be ignored in order to prevent trashing of the code signing settings?

Comment: you can just set code signing to "iPhone Developer" and it should take care of it automatically.

Comment: @mike - That is right! How do I mark this question as answered? I can vote up your comment but that leaves the question itself unanswered ... can you please put it down as an answer as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just set code signing to "iPhone Developer" and it should take care of it automatically.